# How to change the font of the TextArea without changing the font of the Buttons?

Tags: java, fonts, awt, textarea

I am making a text editor for fun.

The problem which I am facing is to change the font of the `TextArea`.

The `setFont` method of the `Frame` changes the font of the text area as well as it changes the font of the `Button` controls.

How to change the font of the text area so it will not effect the font of the buttons?

```
Diary()
{
    ...
    this.setFont(new Font("courier",Font.PLAIN,18));
    ...
}
```

This changes the font of the text area as well as the buttons.

How to change the font of the text area only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should target only the TextArea with the **setFont** method

```
    TextArea ta=new TextArea();
    ta.setFont(new Font("courier",Font.PLAIN,18));
```